# strange SQL query behaviour

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL query from the logs `select content = 5%id%201=1 from pages` the thing is that it runs and returns some values. I tried to find what it does but i hit a dead end. Anyone has some explanation on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks meaningless to me. It will return `1` for a row with `id = 4` *and* `content = '1'`, or for rows with `id != 4` and `content = '0'` or a string that cannot be cast to integer; `0` for all other rows. Seems too contrived to do anything useful.

Comment: This returns `1`. `select content = 5%id%201=1 from (select 'foo' as content, 1 as id) pages`.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is

`content = 5%id%201=1`

means [value of] `content` column IS EQUAL TO (((5 Modulo [value of] `id`) Modulo `201`) IS EQUAL TO 1)

May be the paranthesis order needs to be re-arranged but the idea is it will show either 0 or 1 in the result.

[Click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) for documentation of the MODULO function in MySQL